# How to Display only the Working Directory Name in Shell Prefix?

Tags: bash, prompt

I'm currently working in a **really** long directory. Probably something like:

```
~/Documents/c_prog/this_is_a_really_long_project_name/sub_directory/test_case/
```

It would be awesome if I could execute a command when I'm in this directory and it would only show *`sername@hostname ~/test_case$`  instead of this wall of text. When I restart bash it should just be normal again. I'm totally fine with executing this command every time I'm in this directory.

How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Try setting `PROMPT_DIRTRIM=1`. It's not exactly what you want, but shortens the directory considerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(`bash` 4 or later)

If you set `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` to a non-zero number, it will replace directories after `~` with `...`, retaining the given number of trailing directories. Setting it to 1, for example, will give you

```
username@hostname ~/.../test_case$
```

Comment: Thank you really much! Do I have to put it in my `.bashrc`. It somehow doesn't seem to work if I just write it in the command-line.

Comment: I forgot to check before posting; `PROMPT_DIRTRIM` was introduced in `bash` 4; you appear to be using an earlier version.

Comment: That is quite possible. I'm actually on a Mac at the moment. I'll check right away :) Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Mac OS X still ships with `bash` 3.2.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw it as well. I tried to write a small bash script to update my $PS1 to something with `\W`(like the answer above mentioned). But somehow my PS1 isn't updating.. Do you have any idea why? The script looks like this: `#!/bin/bash    echo This is a test!    export PS1=">"` The Test phrase is printed, but the variable doesn't change...

Comment: Oh, I just read that export doesn't affect subshells.

Comment: Generally, you don't need to export `PS1`; only `bash` uses it, and it's generally set from `.bashrc` when `bash` starts up.

Answer (score 5):

Replace the `\w` escape sequence in your normal `PS1` with `\W`. Thus, from your example, it would be something like:

```
PS1='\u@\h \W\$ '
```

Comment: That only replace `/home/user` with `~`; it affect the rest of the path.

Comment: No, `\W` shows the basename of the current directory, replacing it with `~` only if the CWD is the homedir. Read `man bash`.

Comment: I did, but misread and misremembered. Sorry.

Comment: This is why I love stackexchange. 5 minutes in and already got a quick solution!

Comment: I tried to put it into a bash script: `#!/bin/bash export PS1=">"` but it doesn't seem to change anything. What am I doing wrong? I added the path the file is located in to my PATH in `.bashrc_profile` and made it executable. I can tell the script is being executed by adding an echo`but somehow PS1 doesn't change.

Comment: When you alter the environment in a bash script, the change doesn't propagate to your currently running shell. Type it by hand, or type `source path/to/script.sh`.